# NodeJS - Associations 1 : 1

Tags: node.js, associations, sequelize.js

I'm having trouble getting my associations to work, I have a User object and an Image Object. I create the records but when I try to Select that it tells me "[Error: Image (Image) is not associated to User!]"

Heres the User Association:

```
User.belongsTo(models.Image);
Image.hasOne(
         models.User, {
         foreignKey: 'ImageId',
         as: 'User'
       });
```

I'm using Postico and I can see the relationship is there on ImageId in the Users table. Anyone have a clue why this isn't working?

Comment: did try to use just one of them `belongsTo` **or** `hasOne`? if I remember correctly it should works.

Comment: I've tried that and it still gives me that error.

Comment: How are you trying to select?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I had bad form in my User model. so the associations weren't getting created for the User model.